# Angularjs failed to instantiate module thitch ’angular-file-saver’

Tags: javascript, angularjs, save-as, filesaver.js

How to right add angular-file-saver in AngularJS project?
I trying to implement:  [angular-file-saver](https://github.com/alferov/angular-file-saver) (FileSaver.js version for Angularjs) But it's not working.

1)  installing filesaver file upload via bower with the command:

```
bower install angular-file-saver --save
```

2) I am trying to addition FileSaver.js module in app.js , but in browser console after starting have error:

```
window.mmvvtApp = angular.module('mmvvt', ['ngBootstrap', 'ngFileSaver',...
Failed to instantiate module mmvvt due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.26/$injector/modulerr?p0=...)
```

If i remove the 'ngFileSaver' from function then I am not facing the issue but when I put it in the function legislator and try to call it I get the issue.

May be non compatible versions: AngularJS#1.2.26 and angular-file-saver#1.1.3 don’t work together ?

Can someone help me please?
Thank you.

Comment: A common reason why the module fails to load is that you've forgotten to include the file with the defined module or that the file couldn't be loaded. The error message should provide additional context.

Comment: try removing ng-app from your code and making sure that you add `<script src="./node_modules/file-saver/FileSaver.min.js"></script>` also

Comment: Thank you georgeawg and Akber Iqbal for valuable comments! You're rights!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Earned after include in file "WEB-INF/jsp/main.jsp" next code:

```
<script src="bower_components/angular-file-saver/dist/angular-file-saver.bundle.js"></script>
```

AngularJS#1.2.26 and angular-file-saver#1.1.3 work together correctly.